# How get selected value dynamically from a multiple select using MaterializeCss

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, materialize

(there is similar questions they don't helped me)

I'm using the HtmlHelper @Html.ListBoxFor to create a multiple select. My problem is that he creates this:

```
<ul id="select-options-9658d214-b306-e25f-c4f4-70d48cd6ba08" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown multiple-select-dropdown active" style="width: 278.234px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block;">
   <li class="">
     <span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>test1</span>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <span><input type="checkbox"><label></label>test2</span>
   </li>
   /*...*/
</ul>

<select id="ItemId" multiple="multiple" name="userStringList" onchange="test()" class="initialized">
  <option value="test1">netsendev</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  /*...*/
</select>
```

How can I get the user selected item's in jquery like:

```
$('select').change(function () {
      console.log($("#toto option:selected"));
    })
```

e.g: If I click on the first option, an alert windows will pop and the value inside will be test1.

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach a click event to your select element in jquery like this

```
$("#itemId").click(function() {
});
```

and within that you can find the selected value like this

```
alert($('#ItemId option:selected').val());
```

here is a fiddle for it

https://jsfiddle.net/7qm3ncLp/

Comment: Doesn't works :/ I did that at start but doesn't works. It's seems like the select generated by @Html.ListBoxFor only use the <ul> and <li> to work, cause when I do some interaction changement are on the <li>